# Why does no dictionary carry the word 'non-affair', though all carry 'nonevent'?

Tags: nouns, negation, is-it-a-word, prefixes

I came across the word “non-affair” in Jeffery Archer’s novel *Kane and Abel*, which I just finished reading yesterday. The word appears in the following sentence (p. 544):

> “She couldn’t recall another occasion when she was so aware of a first
>   kiss. When he left her in the shadows of Fifty-Seventh Street, she
>   realized that this time he had not mentioned tomorrow. She felt
>   slightly wistful about the whole **non-affair**.”

I took 'non-affair' simply as the absence of any positive actions / events, and thought the word should be in every dictionary. But, curiously enough, Oxford, Cambridge, and Merriam-Webster don't include “non-affair” as a headword despite its casual look, though they include several dozens of “non+noun” compounds ranging from 'non-aggression,' 'non-appearance,' 'non-event' to 'non-stop,''non-violent,' and 'non-white.'

Google's NGram Viewer neither show any instances of 'non-affair.'

Is “non-affair” a well-used English word, or just a coinage by the author?

Comment: I think you answered your own question.

Comment: You can always derive new “words” using productive combining forms. That doesn’t mean they all go in the dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really a coinage by Archer. It's simply a compound created by applying the standard rule in English that allows anyone to create a negative form by prefixing the negative /non-/ to a noun (*non-affair*) or adjective (*non-significant* [for statistics instead of *insignificant*]). This kind of word creation is rule-governed, so the words usually don't appear in the dictionary unless they're frequently used. Sometimes a good dictionary will list a number of such words under a popular headword but won't define them, e.g. Merriam-Websters 3rd Unabridged:

"Main Entry: non-

Function:prefix 
Etymology:Middle English, from Middle French, from Latin non not, from Old Latin noenum, from ne- not + oinom, neuter of oinos one * more at NO, ONE

: not : reverse of : absence of: *nonacademic, nonconformity, nonbreakable, nonproductive, nonintervention, non-Arabic, non-Mormon, nonrush hours*"

Answer (score 3):

It is fairly common.  I think NGram may be having an issue with the hyphenated use.  The fact that it's not in the dictionary directly is not remarkable because the "non-" prefix is standard no matter which word it's in front of.

It could be related to this definition of "[affair](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affair)":

> a matter occasioning public anxiety, controversy, or scandal

So a non-affair is a matter that is non-controversial, non-worrisome, and lacking in scandal.  In other words: dull.

Or as jwpat7 pointed out, this other one:

> An adulterous relationship.

Meaning that the kiss in the quoted passage was wholly innocent.  Either way, there's not much to see here beyond the literal meaning.

Comment: I think you've missed the meaning of *[affair](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/affair#Noun)*, which I imagine in this case to be sense 5, “An adulterous relationship”, a relationship he and she don't have.  But I haven't read the book recently enough to remember particular circumstances.

Comment: @jwpat7 - Err, yes - you might be right now that I read that particular passage again.  It can be either definition though, really, depending on the context.

Answer (score 1):

The hyphen is a special operator for Google Ngrams, but, as their [help page](http://books.google.com/ngrams/info) explains:

> Because users often want to search for hyphenated phrases, put spaces on either side of the - sign.

Here's a [working Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=non+-+affair&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) showing the word is used:

[image: Ngram showing non-affair in use from 1800 to 2000, and a steady rise from around 1900 to a five-fold use in 2000]